# I want to upload images with text from a form to an express server

Tags: reactjs, express, frontend, fetch, backend

i'm using react, express, mongodb and i want to save the form data entered by user into my database, i've got to the point of saving just text fields and response is of status code 200 but when i try to add images it gives me 500 and saves only the text fields, and i've tried everything but can't get a hold of what's missing.
i'm using multer and fetch.

this is the client side

```
  import React , {Component} from 'react';
import AdminHeader from './AdminHeader';
import AdminFooter from './AdminFooter';
import { Label, Button, Row, Col, Form } from 'reactstrap';
import { baseUrl } from '../shared/baseUrl';
import axios from 'axios';
class AddAppart extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      areaName: '' ,
      description: '',
      shortDescription: '',
      price: '',
      imageFile: null
    };
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  onChange(e) {
      if (e.target.id === 'areaName') {
        this.setState({ areaName: e.target.value });
    } else if (e.target.id === 'description') {
        this.setState({ description: e.target.value });
    } else if (e.target.id === 'shortDescription') {
        this.setState({ shortDescription: e.target.value });
    } else if (e.target.id === 'price') {
        this.setState({ price: e.target.value});
        console.log(e.target.value);
    }else if (e.target.id === 'imageFile') {
      this.setState({ imageFile: e.target.files[0]});
      console.log(e.target.value);
    }
  }
  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch((baseUrl+'appartments/'), {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json', 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        areaName: this.state.areaName,
        description: this.state.description,
        shortDescription: this.state.shortDescription,
        price: this.state.price,
        image: this.state.imageFile
      }),
    })
    this.setState({
      areaName: '' ,
      description: '',
      shortDescription: '',
      price: ''
    });
  }
  // handleSubmitFile(){
  //   fetch((baseUrl+'sendfiles'), {
  //     method: 'POST',
  //     body: JSON.stringify({
  //       imageFile: this.state.imageFile
  //     })
  //   })
  // }
  handleSubmitForm(){

      let data = new FormData();
      data.append("imageFile", this.state.imageFile);
      data.set("shortDescription", this.state.shortDescription);
      data.set("areaName",this.state.areaName);
      data.set("description",this.state.description);
      data.set("price",this.state.price);
      fetch((baseUrl+'appartments/'), {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data
    })
    this.setState({
      areaName: '' ,
      description: '',
      shortDescription: '',
      price: ''
    });
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <>
        <AdminHeader />
        <div className="container">
          <h3>Enter Appartment Information</h3>
          <hr />
          <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} id="MyForm">
            <Row className="form-group">
              <Col>
                <Label htmlFor="areaName">Area Name</Label>
                <input model=".areaName" type="text" onChange={this.onChange} id="areaName" className="form-control" innerRef={(input) => this.areaName = input}></input>  
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row className="form-group">
              <Col>
                <Label htmlFor="description">Description</Label>
                <input model=".description" type="text" onChange={this.onChange} id="description" className="form-control" innerRef={(input) => this.description = input}></input>  
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row className="form-group">
              <Col>
                <Label htmlFor="shortDescription">Short Description</Label>
                <input model=".shortDescription" type="text" onChange={this.onChange} id="shortDescription" className="form-control" innerRef={(input) => this.shortDescription = input}></input>  
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row className="form-group">
              <Col>
                <Label htmlFor="price">Price</Label>
                <input model=".price" type="number" id="price" onChange={this.onChange} className="form-control" innerRef={(input) => this.price = input}></input>
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row className="form-group">
              <Col>
                <Label htmlFor="imagesUpload">Images Upload</Label>
                <input model=".imageFile" type="file" multiple id="imageFile" className="form-control" innerRef={(input) => this.imageFile = input}></input>
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Button type="submit" className="bg-primary">Submit</Button>
          </Form>
        </div>
        <AdminFooter />
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default AddAppart;
```

as you see i've tried using FormData and another request url

this is server side

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'public/images');
    },

    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
});

const imageFileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    if(!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/)) {
        return cb(new Error('You can upload only image files!'), false);
    }
    cb(null, true);
};

const upload = multer({ storage: storage, fileFilter: imageFileFilter});

const appartRouter = express.Router();

appartRouter.use(bodyParser.json());


appartRouter.route('/')
.options(cors.corsWithOptions, (req,res) => {
    res.sendStatus(200);
})
.post(cors.corsWithOptions,upload.array('image'), (req,res,next) =>{
    Appartments.create(req.body)
    .then((appartment) => {
        var files = [].concat(req.files);
        for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
          file = files[i];
          appartment.image.push({"image": file.path});
        }
        appartment.save();
        console.log('Appartment Created ', appartment);
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
        res.json(appartment);
    }, (err) => next(err))
    .catch((err) => next(err));
})
```

when i comment the loop of saving the files to the database status code 200 when it's working gives 500 and in both cases only text fields are saved

EDIT:
I've found a way to use axios and form data and when posting, status becomes 200 okay but image array field is empty

```
handleSubmitFinalIsa(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    var formData = new FormData();
    for (const key of Object.keys(this.state.image)) {
        formData.append('image', this.state.image[key])
    }
    formData.set("shortDescription", this.state.shortDescription);
    formData.set("areaName",this.state.areaName);
    formData.set("description",this.state.description);
    formData.set("price",this.state.price);
    axios.post("https://localhost:3886/appartments", formData, {
    }).then(res => {
        console.log(res.data)
    })
  }
```

EDIT2: after the first edit i realized i didn't track the input file change just added onChange and finally it worked

Comment: Have you tried converting the image to a base64 string and uploading that?

Comment: I don't know how to do it actually